# Files larger than 500 kilobytes are not allowed

Tags: uploads, errors

This is a very strange problem as illustrated on the picture 
[image]

Comment: I am having trouble locating this exact message in WP core. Are you using any possibly related plugins? Can you find this string in your installation?

Comment: This could be a limit setup by your web host on the server level. If your php.ini is updated to allow larger sizes and you still cannot upload there's not much you'll be able to do other than contact your host.

Comment: @GregMcMullen, please look at the picture and see what it says :)

Comment: @Rarst yeah me too. I am using a plugin called userpro to create fancy user profiles. It has an internal file size limit set to 8Mb. I have no problem uploading files through that plugin and also here I can't find that string.

Comment: @Johankat - well then that just doesn't make any sense, sorry about that. If it were me, I'd still double check with my web host about their limits.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your plugins and then uploading?

Comment: @GregMcMullen I checked with them. The limits you see above "...Upload: 96Mb" are reflected by the settings set forth by php.ini. Thus set by the host

Comment: @user42826 That was a good idea, but no cigar. I just disabled the userpro plugin and tried to upload a file, but I was meet with the same message.

Comment: I would disable ALL plugins.  I do it by renaming the plugin directory to 'plugins.bak'

Comment: I disabled all the plugins. Purged the cache and of cause it all started to work again. I have sent a support ticket to the author. Thanks all!